# Change the name text type to auto number - custom setting

Tags: customsetting

Is it possible to change the standard name field from text type to auto number in custom setting. Or it is possible to increase the text size of the name field in custom setting.

Answer (score 2):

Custom Setting Name fields have a fixed length and type. You cannot alter either. You might want to vote on [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000LhFtAAK), but it doesn't yet have a lot of traction.